# Adding a standard msg within the custom msg

Tags: custom-message

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I've made my custom message following the tutorial [here](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingMsgAndSrv).
It works fine. What i want to do is to include some information in my message, as a twist.msg, for instance.

How can I declare this on my .msg file?
Something like this? :

```
geometry_msgs/Twist Base
geometry_msgs/Quaternion Turret
uint8  battery
```

would this work when catkin making all the custom messages?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/218069/adding-a-standard-msg-within-the-custom-msg/) by [cjusto](https://answers.ros.org/users/22283/cjusto/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2015-09-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is the correct way to define the message defintion. In addition:

1. Make sure you add proper dependencies to `geometry_msgs`  and `std_msgs` in your package's `package.xml` and your `CMakeLists.txt` files.
2. You need to also add those dependencies to `generate_messages` macro in package's `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
generate_messages(
  DEPENDENCIES
  std_msgs
  geometry_msgs
)
```

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2015-09-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cjusto](https://answers.ros.org/users/22283/cjusto/) on 2015-09-22**:
Thank You so much Mani.

As soon as I finish all the message content, i'll make them and I'll let You know on the success.

:)

**Comment by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) on 2015-09-22**:
You are welcome. Hopefully it will compile without any hassle.